# Creating a New Column with First Names

Tags: r

I would like to add a new column to my data frame with first names. I am new to R, and I dont know how to do this. Thank you so much for your help.

My data frame (a small portion of it):

```
 name
 Carl J. Johnson
 David Marcus
 A. Anna Jane Lue
```

I want to create a new data frame like this:

```
 name              first_name
 Carl J. Johnson   Carl
 David Marcus      David
 A. Anna Jane Lue  A.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`

```
df$first_name <- sub("(\\w+\\.?).*", "\\1", df$name)

df
#              name first_name
#1  Carl J. Johnson       Carl
#2     David Marcus      David
#3 A. Anna Jane Lue         A.
```

OR in inverted way

```
sub("\\s+.*", "", df$name)
#[1] "Carl"  "David" "A."
```

Or `stringr::word` returns by default the first word.

```
stringr::word(df$name)
#[1] "Carl"  "David" "A."
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. And how do I add this output as a column to my data frame?

Comment: @lily Same like first option `df$first_name <- sub("\\s+.*", "", df$name)` or `df$first_name <- stringr::word(df$name)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dataframe is `df`, you could use `gsub`

```
df$first_name <- gsub(" .*$", "", df$name)
# [1] "Carl"  "David" "A."
```

The regex is basically saying, after the first white space (), for any character (`.*`), until the end of the string (`$`), replace that with nothing (`""`).